# Align subscript

Tags: symbols, subscripts, superscripts

When i put the code `$(f_{\mathcal{X}},f_{\mathcal{X}}^{\partial})$` I get the following:

[image]

But I want the subscripts to be aligned. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noticed, LaTeX will shift down a subscript when there is a superscript above it to make room. What you need to do is have LaTeX pretend there is something in a superscript above. You can do this by adding a superscript to the first *f* of `\vphantom{\partial}`:

```
$(f^{\vphantom{\partial}}_{\mathcal{X}},f_{\mathcal{X}}^{\partial})$
```